# Difficulty in Retrieving Order Details from Shopify Using Python and the Shopify API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

"I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve order details from Shopify using Python. I've been exploring the Shopify API documentation, but I'm having trouble understanding how to authenticate and make requests to fetch specific order information. Could someone provide a code example or guide me through the process of using the Shopify API with Python to retrieve order details? Any help would be greatly appreciated!"

"I have tried reviewing the Shopify API documentation and exploring the Python requests library for making API calls. I was expecting to successfully authenticate with the Shopify API and retrieve specific order details using Python, but I'm encountering challenges in understanding the authentication process and constructing the correct API requests."